# Get PageFactory IWebElement By locator

Tags: c#, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have a situation where I would like to get the 'By' locator used to find an element. I have the elements initialized using **PageFactory**.

Something like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class Page
{
    private IWebDriver _driver;

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "Username")]
    public IWebElement TxtUsername { get; set; }

    public Page(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        _driver = driver;
        PageFactory.InitElements(_driver, this);
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        By locator = GetLocator(TxtUsername); //Not real function
        IWebElement e = _driver.FindElement(locator);
    }
}
```

I know that I can get the Id from the GetAttribute, but it does not solve in case I located the element using XPath or if the element simply does not have an ID.

Like this:

```
By locator = By.Id(element.GetAttribute("id"));
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible simply because there is never any reference kept of *how* you found that element. When you call `.FindElement` it's only interested in finding the element and returning it, it isn't all that interested in remembering *how* you found it.

Your only solution would be to keep a reference *yourself*, by making a class that keeps a record of it.

Something like:

```
public class SeleniumElement : IWrapsElement
{
    private IWebElement cachedElement;

    private By mechanismUsed;

    public SeleniumElement(IWebElement element, By locatorUsed)
    {
        mechanismUsed = locatorUsed;
        cachedElement = element;
    }

    public IWebElement WrappedElement
    {
        get
        {
            return cachedElement;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Arran is correct - you can get an element based on the locator, but you can't convert an element to a locator.

Comment: Hi Arran, thanks for the answer. Please check my answer just bellow.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the replies, but I managed using Reflection to do exactly what I wanted.

Here's my implementation in C#:

```
    private By GetLocator(IWebElement element)
    {
        // Retrieve a FieldInfo instance corresponding to the field
        FieldInfo field = element.GetType().GetField("bys", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        // Retrieve the value of the field, and cast as necessary
        return ((List<By>)field.GetValue(element))[0];
    }
```

**NOTE:** this implementation only works for elements initialized with PageFactory.

Comment: This won't work with the ByChained functionality - as you can pass in many different ways of locating elements. I am also surprised this works at all. I was under the impression it would only keep a record of the `By` used when you are using the `PageFactory` (and the `FindsBy` attribute).

Comment: This won't work for a regular `RemoteWebElement` or a subclass thereof. It will only work if you're using the `PageFactory`.

Comment: After further consideration, I can't let this one go. You've done several things that may confuse someone discovering this question and your answer at a later time. The field you are using is not a member of the `RemoteWebDriver` class which all current .NET implementations use, so if a user is not using the `PageFactory`, this code will throw an exception. You've also made it an extension method on the `IWebElement` interface, which could further confuse the issue. Finally, even using this code with `PageFactory`, you're not guaranteed to get the actual locator used to find the element.

Comment: I tested not using PageFactory and it really does not work. I edited the question and the answer to clarify the situation and the solution (also removed the extension method). Thank you for the replies.